# Looking for a better way to handle periodic boundary condition on numpy array or list in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a set of a large dataset (2-dimensional matrix) of about 5 to 100 rows and 5000 to 25000 columns. I was told to extract a strip out of each row, the strip length is given. For each row, the strip is begin filled from a random position on the row and all the way up, if the position is beyond the length of the row, it will pick the entries from the beginning like the periodic boundary. For example, assume a row has 10 elements,

```
row = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

the position is picked to 8 and the strip length is 4. The strip will then be `[9, 10, 1, 2]`

I am trying to use NumPy to do the computation at first

```
A = np.ones((5, 8000), order='F')
import time
L = (4,3,3,3,4) # length for each of the 5 strips
starttime = time.process_time()
for i in range(80000):
    B = []
    for c, row in enumerate(A):
        start = random.randint(0,len(row)-1)
        end = start+L[c]
        if end>len(row)-1:
            sce = np.zeros(L[c])
            for k in range(start, end):
                sce[k-start] = k%len(row)
        else:
            sce = row[start:end]
        B = sce

print(time.process_time() - starttime)
```

I don't have a good way to handle the boundary condition so I just break it into two cases: one when the whole strip is within the row and one when parts of the strip are beyond the row. This code works and takes about 1.5 seconds to run. I then try to use the list instead

```
A = [[1]*8000]*5
starttime = time.process_time()
for i in range(80000):
    B = []
    for c, row in enumerate(A):
        start = random.randint(0,len(row)-1)
        end = start+L[c]
        if end>len(row)-1:
            sce = np.zeros(L[c])
            for k in range(start, end):
                sce[k-start] = k%len(row)
        else:
            sce = row[start:end]
        B = sce

 print(time.process_time() - starttime)
```

This one is about 0.5 seconds faster, it is quite surprised I expect NumPy should be faster!!! Both codes are good for the small size of the matrix and a small number of iteration. But in the real project, I am going to deal with a very large matrix and a lot more iterations, I wonder if there is any suggestion to improve the efficiency. Also, is there is any suggestion on how to handle the periodic boundary condition (neater and higher efficiency)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you create the array `A` before timing it, both solutions will be equally fast because you are just iterating over the array. But i am actually not sure on why the pure python solution is quicker, maybe it has to do with collection-based iterators (enumerate) are better suited for primitive python types?

Looking at the example with one row, you want to take a range of elements from the row and wrap around the out-of-bounds indices. For this I would suggest doing:

```py
row = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
start = 8
L = 4
np.take(row, np.arange(start, start+L), mode='wrap')
```

output:

```py
array([ 9, 10,  1,  2])
```

This behavior can then be extended to 2 dimensions by specifying the `axis` keyword. But working with uneven lengths in `L` does make it a bit trickier, because working with non-homogeneous arrays you will loose most of the benefits from using numpy. The work-around is to partition `L` in a way that equally sized lengths are grouped together.

If I understand the whole task correctly, you are given some start value and you want to extract each corresponding strip length along the second axis of `A`.

```py
A = np.arange(5*8000).reshape(5,8000) # using arange makes it easier to verify output
L = (4,3,3,3,4) # length for each of the 5 strips
parts = ((0,4), (1,2,3)) # partition L (to lazy to implement this myself atm)
start = 7998 # arbitrary start position

for part in parts:
  ranges = np.arange(start, start+L[part[0]])
  out = np.take(A[part,:], ranges, axis=-1, mode='wrap')
  print(f'Output for rows {part} with length {L[part[0]]}:\n\n{out}\n')
```

Output:

```
Output for rows (0, 4) with length 4:

[[ 7998  7999     0     1]
 [39998 39999 32000 32001]]

Output for rows (1, 2, 3) with length 3:

[[15998 15999  8000]
 [23998 23999 16000]
 [31998 31999 24000]]
```

Although, it looks like you want a random starting position for each row?

Comment: Wow, that is so neat. Thanks @Kevin.